# Is pretty XStream serialization feasible with Scala?

Tags: xml, json, scala, xstream

I'm trying out XStream as a way to quickly serialize objects to Xml or JSON to send over the wire, and deserialize.  I do want the XML/JSON to be simple/clean.

It seems to work well, I've added a few aliases, but now I've hit a problem, this code:

```
println(new XStream.toXML(List(1,2,3)))
```

produces this XML:

```
<scala.coloncolon serialization="custom">
  <unserializable-parents/>
  <scala.coloncolon>
    <int>1</int>
    <int>2</int>
    <int>3</int>
    <scala.ListSerializeEnd/>
  </scala.coloncolon>
</scala.coloncolon>
```

I *think* what is going on is that the Scala List class has its own custom serialization... I wonder if there is a way to override that? I'd prefer to get:

```
<list>
  <int>1</int>
  <int>2</int>
  <int>3</int>
</list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to write a Converter for Scala's List to get xml as shown above, see:

[How can I get XStream to output Scala lists nicely? Can I write a custom converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753511/how-can-i-get-xstream-to-output-scala-lists-nicely-can-i-write-a-custom-converte)

Answer (score 1):

The "coloncolon" class, or `::`, which is actually called `cons`, is a subclass of Scala's `List`. It is used to store the actual elements of a `List`. The only other `List` subclass is the class of the singleton object `Nil`, which represents the empty list.

This is actually doing a reasonable job of serializing it, though it is storing the subclass name -- perhaps a problem when you desserialize it.

I wonder how does it serialize `Nil`.

Comment: I'm trying to find an easy way to generate XML output for a webservice, and the xml generated by by cons doesn't seem appropriate for that type of use. I'm sure I could implement a Converter, I just wonder how many Converter's I'll need to implement :)