# automatic xml conversion in scala

Tags: scala

Let's say I have the following class:

class Person(val firstName:String, val lastName:String)

Is there an automatic way to generate xml from this class without having to hand create a toXml() method? Ideally the output would be something like:

```
    <Person>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Smith</lastName>
    </Person>
```

It seems like there should be a way to do this without having to write all that out manually. Perhaps there is a trait I haven't found yet?

Answer (score 5):

For `case` classes (or other subclasses of `Product`), this was once very easy to write generically: the name can be retrieved with `productPrefix`, all values are iterable via `productIterator` and the names of the fields via `productElementName`.

Unfortunately, `productElementName` has only had a very short life: it was added in [revision 20958](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/20958) and removed in [revision 21223](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/changeset/21223), apparently because it added too much weight to case classes (there's also an [open ticket](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2948) for it).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is such a magic trait. You could use something like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org) to accomplish this. However, it doesn't seem print all Scala classes that pretty automatically, so you probably need to write your own converter. [Someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753511/how-can-i-get-xstream-to-output-scala-lists-nicely-can-i-write-a-custom-converte) has already done so in the case of Lists, I guess for your example you might need something similar.